# Gmail spam folder shortcut

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, gmail

I have a lot of labels and would like a shortcut to easily navigate to the spam folder. Unfortunately I can't find a keyboard shortcut to get there.

Which is the fastest way?

Comment: First. a keyboard shortcut likely does not exist, if it does exist, then Google has documented it on their website.  Second, questions about Google Mail, are not within scope here at Superuser.

Comment: what does this mean? "not within scope here at Superuser"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<kbd>G</kbd> then <kbd>L</kbd> will let you jump to a label. You just need to complete "spam" and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Alternatively, <kbd>/</kbd> will jump to the search bar, then you need merely type `in:spam` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Those are the shortest key combos I can find to get to your spam bin.

Comment: +1 Where did you find `g + L`? I can't see it [here](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6594)

Comment: Under "Jumping". "Go to Label". That's a lowercase "L", not an uppercase "i".

Comment: but is there any difference between `g+l` and `g+L`?

Comment: No. I was just trying to distinguish between "l" and "I", which look identical in sans serif fonts.

Comment: This is great! Now, how about a shortcut to mark a message as not spam? In the shortcuts the closest thing I found was "y" (remove label) but when I tried that it just said "conversation archived" and nothing happened (as far as I can tell).

Comment: To answer my own question, I found that when viewing messages in spam I can hit Enter to open a message, then v (Move to), then start typing "inbox".

Strangely, from the message list in spam, if I hit x to check a message, then v, and start typing "inbox", there are no matches.

Answer (score 0):

There are a list of Gmail keyboard shortcuts [on Google's support site](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6594?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) (sadly, there appears not to be one for the spam folder at this time). To enable the keyboard shortcuts, go into Gmail settings and check `Keyboard shortcuts on`. Don't forget to save your settings.